# What's the difference between these two memset?

Tags: c++, c, memset

```
int color[1001][1001];
int m,n;
m=10;
n=10;
memset(color,0,sizeof(color));
memset(color,0,sizeof(color[0][0])*m*n );
```

What's the difference between these two memset statements?

Any answer will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second one uses undefined variables `m`, and `n`.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius, I have edited the original question providing value of m and n.

Comment: @e0k, The first one is compiling. I have edited the original question.

Comment: unless you want a stupid answer, you should have `m=1001` and `n=1001`

Comment: Is it so hard to check what `sizeof(color)` and `sizeof(color[0][0])` are?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What's the difference between these two memset statements?

The `memset` function takes, the destination, value and count.  The count is `sizeof(color)` which would be `sizeof(int) * 1001 * 1001` for the first call.

For the second it will be `sizeof(int) * 10 * 10`.

The former clears the complete array with zeros, while the latter does it only partially, starting from `color[0][0]` to `color[0][99]`, which relies on the fact that arrays are laid out in a row-major fashion. Relevant excerpt from the C11 standard (draft n1570), **§6.5.2.1 Array subscripting**:

> […] It follows from this that arrays are stored in row-major order (last subscript varies fastest).

Alternatively, if `m = n = 1001` i.e. `m` and `n` actually denote the array's dimensions, the two calls then are the same, [just two different ways of writing it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/483912bbbc218bc9).

Comment: The second one is `sizeof(color[0][0])` not `sizeof(int)` .

Comment: @shibly: since `color[0][0]` is an `int`, it is correct to say that `sizeof(color[0][0]) == sizeof(int)` and hence the equation given is accurate.

Comment: *"The former clears the complete array with zeros, while the latter does it only partially."* - this is true, but it's also noteworthy that the latter clears `color[0][0]` through `color[0][99]`, and *not* `color[i][j]` for `i` and `j` values 0..9.